# Need to upgrade Java EE 1.4 application code to EE 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to upgrade the source code for an existing Java EE 1.4 application to Java EE 7. What I need to do primarily? Any particular steps in order which I need to follow?

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for answers. They are very helpful. Actually the client wants versioning of the code to maintain. The application is very much backward compatible but client requires the code altered as per the EE7 standards (odd it may seem). So the functioning of the application is not the concern, concern is those thousands lines rewritten according to new standards and functional liker ever. There are no third party codes, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking into a time difference of 10 years between 1.4 and 7, which in the IT is **huge**.

Replacing the old J2EE parts by Java EE code basically means rewrite the whole application - so it very much depends on what exactly needs to migrated and how much you can control this scenario.

From an own project where I had to deal with J2EE code I can recommend - if rewriting is not an option - to make the old application run on a new application server and only migrate small parts of it, if possible into a newly deployed application. This worked well, we still have J2EE code in the application and even add/fix small parts in the old code, but it runs together with Java EE code. One thing you have to take care about is the entity manager, because it leads you into trouble if you persist the same data via both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious syntactical changes, I'd suggest looking at what libs you're using and seeing if those are now supported under 7.

When moving application code across versions, most of the time the jump is backwards compatible (I'd say in your case it won't be given such a massive jump) but one of the biggest factors will be if you're using legacy third party code, you'll need to find new supported versions of those products.

This includes say, if you're using a legacy application server and upgrading that.  After all this then you can start to consider any syntactical changes that your IDE should help you with :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend WebSphere Migration Toolkit (an Eclipse plugin). Although it's primary usage is to look for a changes, when migrating from other platforms to WebSphere, it will scan your code, jsp pages, xml files and detect any Java, Java EE related issues also. So you will have rough idea what will need to be changed e.g. in relation to JDK changes.

See some info about that toolkit:

- [WebSphere Migration Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/compmig.html)
- [WebSphere Migration Toolkit download](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Competitive_Migration_V8.5.5)
- [Other WebSphere migration tools](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#filter/sortby=relevance;q=migration)